# Javascript 2D array strange behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I was coding something using javascript arrays but I'm facing a little issue.

I'm running the 'init' function that I've created for 'snake' but the outputs are a little strange for me. I'm sure that's because I'm newbie with javascript. Can anybody explain to me what is happening? And how can I make the code generate the desired output?

```
var snake = {
    direction : null,
    head : null,
    queue : null,

    init: function(){
        this.direction = RIGHT;
        this.queue = []; // 2D ARRAY
        this.head = []; // 1D ARRAY

        this.insert([1,10]);
        this.insert([2,20]);
        this.insert([3,30]);
    },

    insert: function(x,y){
        this.queue.unshift([x,y]); // INSERTS [X,Y]
        this.head = this.queue[0];

        console.log(this.head + "T0"); // prints: 1,10 T0
        console.log(this.head[0] + " T1 "); // prints: 1,10 T1 
        console.log(this.head[1] + " T2 "); // prints: undefined T2 

        /*
            I was expecting (DESIRED OUTPUT):

            this.head to print 1,1

            this.head[0] to print 1

            this.head[1] to print 10

        */ 

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `insert` takes two arguments; one is used as the first value and one as the second value in the array to unshift to the `queue`. when calling the function you only pass one argument (the array `[1,10]`) which well be used as the first element when unshifting, the second element will be undefined.

To solve your problem either call your function using `this.insert(1,10);` or change the function to only take one argument and then `this.queue.unshift(x);`.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. I was calling the function wrongly. Thank you for your help.